# What is the meaning of "Some of it, in its wise restraint, may also be commended to some Spiritualists"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of following sentence?
"Some of it, in its wise restraint, may also be commended to some Spiritualists."

> This contact was not established at
> Rochester, but rather at Stratford in Connecticut, where Davis was a
> witness of the Poltergeist phenomena which broke out in the household
> of a clergyman, Dr. Phelps, in the early months of 1850. A study of these
> led him to write a pamphlet, "The Philosophy of Spiritual Intercourse,"
> expanded afterwards to a book which contains much which the world
> has not yet mastered. **Some of it, in its wise restraint, may also be
> commended to some Spiritualists**. "Spiritualism is useful as a living
> demonstration of a future existence," he says. "Spirits have aided me
> many times, but they do not control either my person or my reason.
> They can and do perform kindly offices for those on earth

[The History of Spiritualism, Vol. I](https://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Some of it

means

> Some of the contents of the pamphlet or book entitled "The Philosophy of Spiritual Intercourse"

"It" is a pronoun and therefore substitutes for a noun or noun phrase.

> Some of it, in its wise restraint, may also be commemded to ...

is admittedly a bit hazy in its meaning. Probably, what was intended is

> Overall, the book is restrained, as is wise, and I recommend consideration of parts of the book

but may mean

> Parts of the book are restrained, as is wise, and I recommend consideration of those parts

The problem with interpretating this sentence is that "its" in the modifying prepositional phrase of "in its wise restraint" may refer to the book or to some of the book. Given the use of the singular "its," I lean toward the book as what is referred to. But it is a badly written sentence. Here is my best guess as to what was intended.

> Overall, the book is wise in its restraint, and therefore I recommend parts of it.